# Javascript Boolean doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I want a button, that pops out after 1 second. And you shall not be able to press it while it's not popped out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pressed1 = false;
    // Audio-Element 'audioElement' gets declared
    $('#button1').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    if(!pressed1){
        audioElement.play();
        pressed1 = true;
        $('#button1').css({backgroundImage: "url(img/button_pressed.png)"});
        setTimeout('$("#button1").css({backgroundImage: "url(img/button.png)"}); pressed1 = false;', 1000);
        return false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    });
});
```

The button pops out after 1 second and 'pressed1' is set to 'false' but i'm not able to press the button again. Even if is set 'pressed1' to 'false' by javascript console!

Comment: Take your code out of the single quotes and wrap it in `function(){}` instead.

Comment: @Starx see Matt Browne's answer for why.

Comment: @Starx - It _is_ necessary. Mash was talking about the code passed to `setTimeout()`, which if in a string will be evaluated in the global scope and not see the `pressed1` variable.

Comment: @Mash, Oh.. you meant anonymous function. Sorry I misunderstoond.

Answer (score 4):

As @Mash suggested, try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pressed1 = false;
    // Audio-Element 'audioElement' gets declared
    $('#button1').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    if(!pressed1){
        audioElement.play();
        pressed1 = true;
        $('#button1').css({backgroundImage: "url(img/button_pressed.png)"});
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#button1").css({backgroundImage: "url(img/button.png)"});
            pressed1 = false;
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    });
});
```

I believe that when you use `setTimeout` with a string of code to be evaluated, instead of a function, that the code gets evaluated internally using `eval()`, which has a different scope (doesn't have access to the variables in your closure).

Comment: ...which works because when you pass a string to `setTimeout()` it gets evaluated in the global context and can't see the local `pressed1` variable. As compared to using `eval()` which _can_ see the local scope...

Answer (score 1):

it is because the variable `pressed1` is locale to the `ready()` method shown here, where you are setting it using the `setTimeout` as shown here the `false` value is set to a global variable called `pressed` not the one you are testing against in your function

Comment: Yes but if he uses a function as we've been suggesting, that function will have access to any variables declared above in the `ready` function.